# OrderedDict flawed order for large keys

Tags: python, sorting, dictionary, python-3.5

```
hybrid_dict = OrderedDict(sorted(hybrid_dict.items(), key=lambda t: t[0]))
for k,v in hybrid_dict.items():
    print(k)
```

output:

```
9148000.0
9149000.0
915000.0
9150000.0
9151000.0 
9152000.0
```

The `915000.0` should not be there.

Why is ordered dict ordering my dictionary like this? `print(hybrid_dict)` gives the same order.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I checked and I think it's because your keys are strings not numbers and strings compare by [Lexicographical order](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lexicographical_order).

To sort them as if they were numbers just modify your `key`-function:

```
from collections import OrderedDict
hybrid_dict = dict.fromkeys(['9148000.0','9149000.0','915000.0','9150000.0','9151000.0','9152000.0'])
hybrid_dict = OrderedDict(sorted(hybrid_dict.items(), key=lambda t: float(t[0])))
for k,v in hybrid_dict.items():
    print(k)
```

which gives:

```
915000.0
9148000.0
9149000.0
9150000.0
9151000.0
9152000.0
```